# Laravel 5.6 helper class

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

Laravel 5.6 , model name is not found in helper class (N:B: helper class is located in App\Helpers\Helper.php)

[image]

Comment: namespace is missing in the code

Answer (score 1):

The model name is not enough for Laravel to retrieve the right class, it needs the namespace too.

You can try this if all your models are in the `App\Models`namespace :

```
public static function getAll($modelName)
{
    $modelName = '\App\Models\' . $modelName;
    return $modelName::all();
}
```

But if it is not the cas, you should send the whole name to your helper method like that :

```
Helper::getAll(\App\Models\User::class);
Helper::getAll(\App\Models\Subfolder\OtherModel::class);
// ...
```

Let me know if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add namespace.

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers; // <--- Add this

class Helper{
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.
first import the Model namespace like this
        `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;`

then, add Model keyword before $model. like
`public function getAll(Model $model){
   // your code
}`

may it can help :)